# a excel table list, how can I combine to an one line string

Tags: python-3.x

I have long list in excel like below:

```
6000 2RS,6000 ZZ,
6001 2RS,6001 ZZ,
6002 2RS,6002 ZZ,
6003 2RS,6003 ZZ,
6004 2RS,6004 ZZ,
6005 2RS,6005 ZZ,
6006 2RS,6006 ZZ,
6007 2RS,6007 ZZ,
6008 2RS,6008 ZZ,
6009 2RS,6009 ZZ,
```

it may more 100 lines, 
how can I combine it into only one line?
the result will be

```
6000 2RS,6000 ZZ,6001 2RS,6001 ZZ,6002 2RS,6002 ZZ,6003 2RS,6003 ZZ,6004 2RS,6004 ZZ,6005 2RS,6005 ZZ,6006 2RS,6006 ZZ,6007 2RS,6007 ZZ,6008 2RS,6008 ZZ,6009 2RS,6009 ZZ,...
```

how it works in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file `with` and split them using `lists`>

```
with open('path to my file', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    mylist = get_your_column()
    print(mylist.split('\n'))
```

Note:`get_your_column` is a function that you should use to iterate over to the column inside your excel that contains your desired list.